# Calling a Module and a Class within a Form

Tags: vb6

I have an Employee class where I call my database connection Module to make a query.

I am getting "Compile Error: Expected function or variable", which I'm not understanding, because I have the `empObj` set at the top of the form.

I would like to return the value from the Employee.getEmployee method. Can someone please show me how to call the Employee class from my form? Do I have to import the class first? I don't believe VB6 supports the `Imports` keyword.

This is my form:

```
Option Explicit

Private empObj As New Employee

Private Sub Form_Load()
  'For testing only
  MsgBox (empObj.getEmployee)
End Sub
```

This is my class:

```
Public Sub getEmployee()
  'ConnectSQL is a database connection
  return ConnectSQL
End Sub
```

And this is the module:

```
Public Function ConnectSQL()
  Set SQLMyconn = New ADODB.Connection
  Set SQLRecset = New ADODB.Recordset
  SQLMyconn.Open "Driver={MySQL ODBC Client Interface};ServerName=localhost;dbq=@testdb"
End Function
```

Comment: Several things:  first, VB6 has no `return` keyword as you are using it.  Second, `ConnectSQL` isn't returning anything.  Third, you need to define `getEmployee` as a function.

Comment: Hi Brian, thank you. I noticed after I posted this that I was calling my connection module and not returning anything. As you can probably tell, I have zero VB experience. I thought that I'd be able to return the object to the form. Can you please show me how this should be done? I can't use a Sub for this? I have to  use a function? I thought a Sub was a function.

Comment: @BrianMStafford, Brian, I changed the Sub to a Function and I'm no longer getting any errors. Can you please tell me how I might actually return the connection object to the form? I tried to just return but it complains about not using GoSub.

Comment: Functions return data and Subs don't return data would be the short answer.

Comment: @BrianMStafford, perfect answer on the differences, thank you!

Comment: @BrianMStafford actually Return is a keyword but only used with the archaic Gosub... hence the specific error the OP is getting. Nonetheless its use here doesn't make sense as you correctly pointed out.;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The basic shell of what you want to do is like this:

```
Option Explicit

Private empObj As Employee

Private Sub Form_Load()
   Set empObj = New Employee
   MsgBox empObj.getEmployee
End Sub

Public Function getEmployee() As String
   getEmployee = ConnectSQL
End Function

Public Function ConnectSQL() As String
   Set SQLMyconn = New ADODB.Connection
   Set SQLRecset = New ADODB.Recordset
   SQLMyconn.Open "Driver={MySQL ODBC Client Interface};ServerName=localhost;dbq=@testdb"

   ConnectSQL = "data from your DB lookup"
End Function
```

Almost every line is different than what you posted, so carefully look at the code.

**EDIT:**

Based on a comment, here's how to modify the code to return a connection object:

```
Option Explicit

Private empObj As Employee

Private Sub Form_Load()
   Set empObj = New Employee
   MsgBox empObj.getEmployee

   Dim MyConnection As ADODB.Connection
   Set MyConnection = ConnectSQL()

   'you can grab and use the connection in your form, too.
End Sub

Public Function getEmployee() As String
   Dim MyConnection As ADODB.Connection
   Set MyConnection = ConnectSQL()

   'use the connection to grab data

   getEmployee = "data from your DB lookup"
End Function

Public Function ConnectSQL() As ADODB.Connection
   Set ConnectSQL = New ADODB.Connection
   ConnectSQL.Open "Driver={MySQL ODBC Client Interface};ServerName=localhost;dbq=@testdb"
End Function
```

Don't forget to close your connection after you are done with it.  To sum up the changes:

1. empObj - you should declare and instantiate your objects separately.
2. MsgBox - no need for the ().
3. Functions vs Subs - the first returns data, the second does not.  Make sure you declare the return type of a function.
4. return - this statement is obsolete and doesn't do what you want.  Instead, assign a value to the name of the function.

Comment: Thank you very much, Brian! This should get me started.

Comment: Brian, can you tell me if it's possible to return the connection object so I can use it elsewhere in the project, instead of querying inside of the MySQL Module and returning the queried values from there?

Comment: @NaN  I updated my sample code to address your last question.

Comment: Brian, again, thank you very much! I'll give this a try on Monday when I get back.