# VB6 and ODBC commands

Tags: vb6, pervasive

I started a thread here, this is a continuation from that post: [Calling a Module and a Class within a Form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58648298/calling-a-module-and-a-class-within-a-form)

I can't find the information I need to successfully query our database. What I need to do is to get a single value from a Pervasive database. I cannot find the list of ODBC commands to do this with.

Can someone please point me to some documentation that deals with these Pervasive ODBC commands? I'm using ADO ODBC for the connection.

EDIT:

I am also attempt to connect to a MySQL database as well and am hitting the same error. Here is a test Sub I created to call my MySQL function. The error is the same for MySQL as it is for Pervasive: "Object variable or With Block variable not set"

```
Public Sub testMe(id)
  Dim MySqlConn As adodb.Connection 'Do I need this here or in the MySQL function?
  Set MySqlConn = ConnectMySQL()
MySqlConn.Open "SELECT * FROM test", MySqlConn, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic
End Function
```

Comment: Have you successfully connected to the database?  If so, just build a `Select` statement to retrieve the data you need.

Comment: Hi Brian. The issue is that I'm not able to test the connection. This is what I've been trying to do since last Thursday, but can't find the OBDC commands for the Pervasive v10 database.

Comment: I'm not clear what you mean by 'test the connection'.  Based on the connection string in your previous post, is your connection open?

Comment: Have you tried https://www.connectionstrings.com/pervasive/

Comment: @BrianMStafford, I'm not sure if it's open or not.

Comment: Try `MySqlConn.Execute` instead, changing the parms as needed.

Comment: Brian, I just tried using Execute and I get the same exact error as with Open; "Object variable or With Block variable not set"

Comment: I would suspect that `MySqlConn` is Nothing.

Comment: Interesting. Is it correct that my MySQLConnect function that we worked on last week, isn't really returning anything? Could this be why? The last line in that function is `MySqlConn.Open "Driver=...` Shouldn't I be returning this somehow?

Comment: Set a break point on the `Execute` statement and inspect the value of `MySqlConn`.

Comment: Yes, Brian, MySqlConn is set to Nothing. You're right.

Comment: Carefully look at your connection function.  Make sure you are saying `Set <function name> = New ADODB.Connection`.  See my posted answer for an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to connect to the database.  According to [this website](https://www.connectionstrings.com/pervasive/) the connection string would be in this format:

> Driver={Pervasive ODBC Client
>   Interface};ServerName=myServerAddress;dbq=@dbname;

Starting with code from your previous post, it could be extended like this:

```
Option Explicit

Public Function getEmployee() As String
   Dim MyConnection As ADODB.Connection
   Dim CM As ADODB.Command
   Dim RS As ADODB.Recordset

   Set MyConnection = ConnectSQL()

   'one way using command objects
   Set CM = New ADODB.Command
   Set CM.ActiveConnection = MyConnection
   CM.CommandType = adCmdText
   CM.CommandText = "select * from <table>"
   Set RS = New ADODB.Recordset
   RS.Open CM, , adOpenStatic, adLockBatchOptimistic

   'another way using just the connection
   Set RS = MyConnection.Execute("select * from <table>")

   'return the data
   getEmployee = RS.Fields(0).Value
End Function

Public Function ConnectSQL() As ADODB.Connection
   Set ConnectSQL = New ADODB.Connection
   ConnectSQL.Open "Driver={MySQL ODBC Client Interface};ServerName=localhost;dbq=@testdb"
End Function
```

Comment: Brian, this works!! I am able to connect to the database now. Here is where I think the issue is happening. I have a module with a ConnectSQL function. When I attempt to use that function, I'm not able to connect. If I move that function into the same class as you have it, then I can connect just fine. Do I need to include that module first into this class in order to be able to use it?

Comment: If you moved and did not modify the function, I'm not sure why that would be.

Comment: Currently, the method you are calling ConnectSQL is in my project, a module called, MySQL. What I would like to do is to call that function in my Employee class, so I can query the data I need. Is this possible, or should I just put the connection information in the class instead, and delete the module?

Comment: Brian, I must have done something to the module function because I now have it working. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Good to hear!  Assuming you have an exe with a class and a Public function in a module, that function should be available everywhere.